# Highlight Item in Android Gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I've spent a lot of time searching on S.O. but without result.

I have a Gridview in my Android App. I want to have the possibility to check multiple items, and this works via the

```
gridview.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

However, when I select an item there is no graphic showing that it is selected...here is my problem: how the *** can I do to make the background of an item to be of any color?

Tried with listSelector...does not work!

**My XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto'
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rollercoders.smartkedex.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AdView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize='BANNER'
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My JAVA Code**

```
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridview.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PokemonDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    gridview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            int selectCount = gridview.getCheckedItemCount();
            switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
```

**My ImageAdapter Class**

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
Integer[] mThumbIds = {/*here there are all the referenced images*/}
```

Comment: declare one value ( if you want handle multiple selection HashSet is a good idea ) in adapter class, and store selected position in it ( in `onItemCheckedStateChanged` you need add your position in your value ) then in `getView` check position is exists in your value or not, if is it do whatever you want to do with selected item, else return view to default state

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so sure I have understood. Could you post a code example please? Thank you